# Model3d x,y position of rendered image in ViewPort3D - FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

Is there any way to get a x,y position and width/height of a `TModel3d` model in `TViewPort3D` in Firemonkey? I need to make a screenshot of textured model, but trimming white space after that seems to be really time consuming, especially when application has to make 1000 of those.

Comment: Perhaps you can make a BMP screenshot of the model on white background and trim away white pixels on that BMP.

Comment: Yes, I know I could do that, but it would be slow.